# The project file cannot be migrated

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I got an error message "Operation could not be completed. The project file cannot be migrated. See the migration report for details." When I was trying to add an existing project into a blank solution... and it seems there's doesn't exist any solution to this problem...

Here's how I tried to add those existing project into the solution:

Right click on the Solution menu > Add > Existing Project... > xxx.vcproj > then click Open

The project folder also contain another sub folder and it has a xxx.exe inside, there is also a file called 'xxx.vcxproj' but I could not open it as well

How could I fix this?

Comment: well you provided no information about what the project contains so no one is going to be able to give you a straight answer.   I will take a guess that you have an installer that is no longer available but again....just guessing

Comment: @Sorceri Edited, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Fixed it like this:

### Unblock files

You might need to do this for each downloaded file

- Right click the file and choose **Properties**
- In the lower-right corner, under **Sercurity**, you might see a dialog stating that the file has been blocked for security reasons. Click **Allow** to unblock it.
- The file could also be **read only**. Uncheck that box if needed.

---

### Take ownership over the files

- Download [this file](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/391187d1472650596-take-ownership-shortcut-add_take_ownership_to_context_menu.reg) to your **desktop** and run it
- Go to the folder containing your project, right-click it and choose **Take Ownership**

[source](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1911-take-ownership-shortcut.html)

---

- Then, open Visual Studio, choose **open project** and select the *.vcxproj file
- If it tells you you need to install additional C++ packages, click **OK** and wait until the install completes (you may need to close visual studio)

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when trying to add a new project from a template.

This is how I fixed it: I went to the solution main folder and opened the file UpgradeLog.htm.

In the Solution section, it tells you what errors it encountered.

I had an error:

ImportOrganization2\ImportOrganization2.csproj: The Web Application Project ImportOrganization2 is configured to use IIS. The Web server 'http://localhost:53196/' could not be found.

The ISS directory did not exist. So I had to edit the .csproj file located in the main solution folder manually, and replace

```
<UseIIS>True</UseIIS> to <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
```

Then save it and add the project in Visual Studio (right click on the folder, Add New Project).

You might find other errors. Make sure your folders and files referenced in the .csproj file also exist.

Answer (score -1):

if its a VB6 project and you are migrating to VB Studio 2015 you have to find this entry at registry.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node]

export it for backup purposes. and the delete it from registry.

run: regedit. find the entry manually. right-click on the entry folder then export

if its not the case copy-paste the migration reports at project folder so we can know more about this issue