# Visual Studio 2017 can't Create new Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just installed the visual studio and .NET Framework 4.7.1

I go on File -> New Project -> Installed -> Visual C#, there is a list of templates, I tried all the templates but all projects I create I got an error message: "Operation could not be completed, The project file 'FILE_PATH' cannot be migrated. See the migration report for details"

I can go in the file path and are folders with an .sln file that I can open on visual studio but they have no files inside

I read about the folder is read-only but, I did't find any solution

I am Using the community version

[image]

Comment: you are inconsistent - can you `create` a brand new project - yes or no?  your question talks about  to opening an `existing` project.

Comment: It appears you're *migrating* a project, not creating one. What does the migration report say (the one that the error message is referring to)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The project file cannot be migrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413945/the-project-file-cannot-be-migrated)

Comment: I am not migrating, I try create on File->New Project, ad there is no migration report, I mean I don't know where is this report

Answer (score -1):

I removed and Installed again, so far it is working.